# What schemas does Databricks create automatically?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

The Databricks "Data Explorer" exposes schemas from the Spark catalog: https://docs.databricks.com/data/index.html

Certain schemas can be automatically created by Databricks. For example, if you attempt to create a table without specifying a schema, it will be assumed to go to the schema called `default`.

What are other automatically generated schemas?

Note: While I welcome all input, I would greatly appreciate an answer supported by some source (ideally Databricks documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's really dependent on different factors:

- `default` exists by default when you use Hive Metastore and Unity Catalog (UC)
- if you use Unity Catalog, then `information_schema` schema/database is created automaticall - it's created for each catalog in the Unity Catalog metastore
- the `main` catalog is also created automatically in each UC metastore
- the `samples` catalog is automatically available in the Unity Catalog - it contains sample data
- there could be also `system` catalog in the Unity Catalog, but it depends on the configuration, previews, etc.